# Windows phone timing out http requests after 1 minute

Tags: http, internet-explorer, windows-phone, timeout, keep-alive

If I make an http request from internet explorer on a windows phone that takes around a minute or more to respond the request fails. I wrote a simple express app that just sleeps for 80 seconds and then responds with a 200 and I can't load it from any windows phone device. It loads just fine from IE9 on desktop though.

Does anyone know of any official documentation that would explain this? Are there any work arounds for dealing with very slow APIs on a windows phone?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed [official documentation explaining this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813827):

> By default, Internet Explorer has a KeepAliveTimeout value of one
>   minute and an additional limiting factor (ServerInfoTimeout) of two
>   minutes. Either setting can cause Internet Explorer to reset the
>   socket.
>
> If either the client browser (Internet Explorer) or the Web server has
>   a lower KeepAlive value, it is the limiting factor. For example, if
>   the client has a two-minute timeout, and the Web server has a
>   one-minute timeout, the maximum timeout is one minute. Either the
>   client or the server can be the limiting factor.

To workaround a request timing out / dealing with slow APIs you need the server to return something periodically to let the browser know the server is still alive / hasn't died and something should actually be received. The how on this is a whole different question which is really on a case by case (or category) basis.

Some related resources I recommend you go over:

- [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)
- [Push technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)
- [The Streaming APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview)

Comment: Thanks for the info. The article claims that IE 5-11 will all timeout after 1 minute but I've tested this on IE 9 and 11 on multiple desktop computers and I've never seen the timeout. I only see requests timing out on windows phone. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @rob All of these settings can be overwritten as system variables. It can also depend on the OS for these defaults. So i'm guessing the 1 min comes from IE while anything over that is OS customization (just a wild guess). Take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813827

Comment: In any case, if you indeed have an API in mind you want to use the 1 minute as a constraint for your design (at most).

Comment: @rob also note that windows phone doesn't actually have IE , but rather Internet Explorer Mobile which is based on the desktop version of Internet Explorer.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile ) .

Comment: I checked my registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings but there is no "KeepAliveTimeout" key that would override the default. Strange that the MS article doesn't mention that it applies to Internet Explorer Mobile but that seems to be the only environment it applies to